In the Azure Pipelines define a variable in UI and use this variable value in the YAML as a compile-time variable
I have a variable defined in UI:

and I want to use the value of the variable to include a template file from a folder named like the value of the variable.
variables:
  - template: '../files/${{ variables.UIDefinedVariable }}/params.yml'
    parameters:
      Parameter1: ${{ parameters.Parameter1 }}

When I try to run the pipeline it gives the error that the file "/files/params.yml" - is not available - this because ${{ variables.UIDefinedVariable }} has no value at compile time so is replaced with an empty string.
Is there any way to make sure that ${{ variables.UIDefinedVariable }} does have the "FOLDER1' value at the compile time without using a parameter instead of variable? Am I using the wrong kind of variables here?

When you set the Variable in Pipeline run UI/Variable Group, the variables will be expanded at runtime.
But the variable used in the templated field need to be expanded at compile time.
So the variable: UIDefinedVariable  will show empty value at the compile time.

Is there any way to make sure that does have the "FOLDER1' value at the compile time without using a parameter instead of variable?

To solve this issue, you need to define the variable value in the YAML file.
For example:
variables:
  - name: UIDefinedVariable
    value: FOLDER1
  - template: '../files/${{ variables.UIDefinedVariable }}/params.yml'
    parameters:
      Parameter1: ${{ parameters.Parameter1 }}

Then the variable value will pass to the template field at compile time.
Update:
To control the value from outside, we need to use the YAML parameters.
For example:
parameters:
  - name: UIDefinedParameter
    type: string
    default: Folder1
  - name: Parameter1
    type: string
    default: test
variables:
  - template: '../files/${{ parameters.UIDefinedParameter }}/params.yml'
    parameters:
      Parameter1: ${{ parameters.Parameter1 }}

We can set the default value of the parameter. Then when we run the Pipeline, we can set the value from outside.
For example:


But obviously i want to be able to control the value of UIDefinedVariable from outside. There is no way to do it?

@BudaFlorin Yes. I am afraid that there is no method can achieve it if you need to use variable. If you decide to use parameters in yaml file, this can be  achieved.

@BudaFlorin I have updated my answer to share the sample to use parameters in yaml pipeline.
